# ArcGIS Online no pop up in raster/tile layer

Tags: raster, arcgis-online, arcgis-online-basemaps, arcgis-online-webmap, tile-layer

I am building a WebGIS using ArcGIS Hub and ArcGIS App Builder.

I have uploaded several Raster files to ArcGIS Online (Tile layer files) from ArcGIS Pro using the Create Map Tile Package tool. Then, I created web maps with 5 of those raster files (Tile layer), and web apps from those web maps.

The issue is that is not possible to get information about those maps itself by clicking on them. That is, there is not a pop up available. In ArcGIS one can click on a pixel and get that pixel value, but in ArcGIS Online, unfortunately, that does not work. Perhaps because in the cloud, those maps are identified as basemaps and not as data layers itself.

May you help me overcome this problem or do you know about an easy solution to solve it?

Comment: I believe you need to publish your raster as a web imagery layer/image service rather than a tile layer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create pop-ups from Raster layers in ArcGIS Online. There are however a few caveats to this.

According to the help:
https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/configure-pop-ups.htm

You can configure pop-ups on an image layer when you're working with a mosaic dataset-based **image service**.

The key word there is Image Service.Have you published the raster layers as an Image Service, or as a Map Service?

Copying straight off this page:

> Pop-ups can also display the pixel values of quantitative data, which
> may represent elevation, precipitation, temperature, reflectance, and
> other such information. There are two types of quantitative pixel
> values that you can configure: Item Pixel Value and Service Pixel
> Value

Confirms that you can also access the pixel values from the raster (as you would in ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro).

You can configure the pop-ups, as you would a Vector feature service, by selecting "Configure Pop-up" (you get here by selecting the three elipses located with the layer in the Table of Contents of the browser).

Comment: I believe you can only publish the raster layers as an image service if you have access to other capabilities that I don´t: ArcGIS Server, Portal, or ArcGIS Image. 
I have published each of the rasters individually online using the "Create Map Tile Package" tool. In the Cloud, they are labelled as a Tile Package and also Tile Layer (Host). Even if I did not find any definition about it, I believe this is a Map Service.
As rasters have the same extent but they relate to different times, when creating a mosaic dataset I am unable to visualize all the 5 rasters but rather just a single one.

Comment: The option to configure pop-ups does not work for me