# Making online interactive map with raster files

Tags: raster, arcgis-online, google-earth, mapping, service-recommendations

ArcGIS Online and Google Earth allow me to upload rasters but only keeps the image, none of the values in the raster are retained. I'd like to make my maps available online and such that the user can click around the raster and see the different values.

Is there a website for this somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of the answers at both of these pages:

https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-online-questions/publishing-a-raster-to-arcgis-online/td-p/518652

[ArcGIS Online no pop up in raster/tile layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/420174/arcgis-online-no-pop-up-in-raster-tile-layer)

You can only include raster data in a pop-up when clicking on a raster layer on a web map if the layer has been published as an Image Service, and ArcGIS Online cannot publish layers as an image service.  Therefore you would need to publish the layer using either ArcGIS Enterprise or at least ArcGIS Server.  (Or some other type of service altogether.)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Google Earth Engine (the cloud-based geo analysis platform) and its "Earth Engine Apps" tool.  In Earth Engine, you can upload raster data, do all sorts of analysis on it if desired, and then publish an "Earth Engine App" that shows your data.  In there, the rasters can be clickable and can show the pixel values, or even charts and other visualizations based on various datasets or time-series at each point.